# Sonar error is null on at least one execution path.Why is this an issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using SonarQube to analyse the code. I have one method as below.
Headers is null on at least one execution path :

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsyncWithHeaders(
    IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory,
    string apiUrl,
    IDictionary<string, string> headers)
{
    var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    if (headers != null || !headers.Any())
    { 
        foreach (var header in **headers**) //here the bug us shown
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
        }
    }
   return await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

Now when I run SonarQube, it is pointing to the headers in foreach loop and shows it as a bug. The message is "headers' is null on at least one execution path.".

How do I  remove this bug?

Comment: I would expect removing `&& !headers.Any()` would solve it without changing functionality. The for each will not execute the statements  when the enumerable has no values.

Comment: Change !headers.Any() to : headers.Count() > 0

Comment: condition is  if (headers != null || !headers.Any())

Answer (score 0):

The `||` operator functions in a way that requires only one of the conditions to be true. In your scenario, if the first condition `headers != null` returns false, the second condition `!headers.Any()` will be attempted. This can result in a problem if you are attempting to execute a LINQ operation on a null collection. My best guess, this is likely why you are receiving this message.

To prevent this issue, I suggest modifying the `||` operator to `&&`. This will allow for the condition to be skipped entirely if the `headers` collection is null.